# Mobile Device info showing 'not set'

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I integrated google analytics with my android app. It's gives very useful information i need, but in Mobile Device info tab, i found some devices are shown as 'not set'. What it means? Am I want to configure any settings to get those data. Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Change the 'primary dimension' to Operating system on the devices screen to get more visibility into 'not set' devices

ref: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/n-LDtWGhZiY

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Turkey, and in my case, these `not set` devices are the devices that are produced by top ISP's or mobile network operators, thus, their information can't be collected by GA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the primary dimension tip. I switched it around with the Mobile Device Info as the primary and the Operating system as the secondary. I then used the screen resolution to have an idea if it's mainly tablets or phones. Cheers!

According to what I found, it means that the data was not able to be collected: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en

Apparently you can use filters to dig deeper, but it seems like it'll take some time to do.